# Returning Top-k Hits on a Field in a Lucene Document

Tags: lucene

I have a Lucene index composed of documents each with two fields, F1 and F2. I perform a search on F1, and collect F2 for the top-k ranked documents. I use the IndexSearcher interface.
In my results, there are a lot of duplicate F2 values, can I ask for the top-k to be over the unique F2 values?

Answer (score 0):

add the F2 values in a hashset , then within duplicate check(use link),add the field value pair in result object...so your result object will not have duplicate values...

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#add%28E%29

Comment: @myahya you cannot avoid duplicates from lucene index...so you have to filter each document before adding to result object